# 301 redirect is not removing the original paths in NGINX

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, nginx

I was trying to redirect a particular URL to a new URL using `rewrite` | `301 redirect` catered by NGINX.

```
if ($request_uri = "/playlist/show/531a5aaefd3401705c000a32") {
   rewrite ^.*$ playlist/all/ redirect;
}
```

If my request URI is `http://servername.com/playlist/show/531a5aaefd3401705c000a32`, then it should redirect to `http://servername.com/playlist/all/`

But what's happening right now is that it the original paths from old URL are still there:

```
http://servername.com/playlist/show/playlist/all/
```

The `/playlist/show/` slashes/paths are still there, so it's redirecting to the wrong URI.

I'm pretty new in handling NGINX. Please bear with me. Thanks!

EDITS:

Here's my conf to be clearer:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.servername.com;
  server_tokens off;
  charset utf-8;
  root /home/site/stm/public;

  location / {
    index index.php;
    # auth_basic "Restricted";
    # auth_basic_user_file /home/site/stm/.htpasswd;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    empty_gif;
    expires 30m;
  }

  if ($request_uri = "/playlist/show/531a5aaefd3401705c000a32") {
    rewrite ^.*$ playlist/all/ redirect;
  }

  if ($request_uri = "/favicon.ico") {
    rewrite ^.*$ /favicon.ico last;
  }

  if ($request_uri !~* ^/(?:static|favicon.ico)) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }


  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

You should never use `if ($uri` or `if ($request_uri` because it's just a very bad method of making `location`.

```
location =/playlist/show/531a5aaefd3401705c000a32 {
    return 302 /playlist/all/;
}
```

Simple, fast, no regexps.

Reference to study:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- [Converting rewrite rules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)
- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And thanks also for awesome reference(s) too :)

Comment: Hi @Vbart, it didn't redirect. Should it be really a 302 or must be a 301?

Comment: It depends on what redirect do you want: temporary (302) or permanent (301).

Comment: Both didn't work maybe some things are blocking rewrites. Thanks anyway

Comment: Check the URI in location carefully, and note, that slashes are important. Your `rewrite` didn't work right because of missing slash at the beginning of `/playlist/all/`. Also avoid using `if`, see http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil